# NativeScript Vue: component not registering on almost identical page (on one page it does, but not on the other)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Good afternoon,

I'm stuck with a problem. And hope you can help me with this. I'll try to explain the scenario.

**Scenario**

I have a product and category page. Both import the 'family tree' component that keeps track of a 'breadcrumb' (for example: Fruit > Soft Fruit > Strawberry). Fruit and soft fruit are the categories and strawberry the product. With the current product/category bolded when active.

In this scenario, each item in the tree is clickable and can be navigated to the category page if the item is a category and to the product page if it is a product.

**Code**

As I mentioned earlier, the 'family tree' component is imported on both pages. The product page existed before, so the tree was imported there before. The way the tree is imported is:

```
@Component({
    name: 'ProductDetails',
    components: {
      > familyTree: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/family-tree/family-tree.vue').default,
        textBlock: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/text-block/text-block.vue').default,
        youtubeFrame: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/youtube-frame/youtube-frame.vue').default,
    }
})
```

With in the Vue page:

```
<family-tree name="productTree" :current-id="productId" :family-tree="familyTree" :view-type="productViewType" />
```

This works as expected. The component is loaded and all items in the tree are displayed.

Now the strange thing is, for the category page I actually do the same, but there I get an error for unknown custom element. In other words, the component 'family tree' is not recognized.

Tree import in category page:

```
@Component({
    name: 'CategoryDetails',
    components: {
      > familyTree: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/family-tree/family-tree.vue').default,
        textBlock: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/text-block/text-block.vue').default,
        youtubeFrame: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/youtube-frame/youtube-frame.vue').default,
    }
})
```

And the .vue:

```
<family-tree name="categoryTree" :current-id="categoryId" :family-tree="familyTree" :view-type="categoryViewType" />
```

I also tried adding the component programmatically (a stackLayout with a ref). Strangely enough, that works.

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(FamilyTree);
        var instance = new ComponentClass({
            propsData: {
                currentId: this.categoryId,
                familyTree: this.familyTree,
                viewType: this.categoryViewType
            }
        });

        instance.$mount(); // pass nothing
        (this.$refs.container as any).appendChild(instance.$el);
```

I have also checked all data and everything is there. There are no null pointers or anything like that.

It's fixed now, by adding it programmatically, but that's not how I want it to be. I just want to be able to call the component via the html tag.

I hope this gives enough information to help me out.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Full code sample:

category-details.vue

```
<template>
    <Page backgroundColor="#EBEBEB" enableSwipeBackNavigation="true">
        <ActionBar android:flat="true" android:backgroundColor="#b6a500">
            <NavigationButton text="Go Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" @tap="$navigateBack" />
        </ActionBar>
        <ScrollView>
            <GridLayout rows="auto, *" columns="*">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout padding="10" backgroundColor="#FFF">
                        <Label :text="category.name" color="#000" class="h1" backgroundColor="#FFF" />
                        <StackLayout ref="familyTreeContainer">
                        </StackLayout>
                        <!-- TODO 2668 -->
                        <!--<family-tree name="categoryTree" :current-id="categoryId" :family-tree="familyTree" :view-type="categoryViewType" />-->
                        <Image :src="category.headlineImage ? category.headlineImageUrl : noImageUrl" height="500px" width="auto" class="bordered" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <text-block v-for="textBlock in category.textBlocks" :text-block="textBlock"></text-block>
                    <StackLayout padding="10" marginTop="5" backgroundColor="#FFF" v-if="category.videoId">
                        <Label text="Video" color="#000" class="t-14" backgroundColor="#FFF" />
                        <youtube-frame :video-id="category.video.url"></youtube-frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout padding="10" marginTop="5" backgroundColor="#FFF">
                        <Label text="Gerelateerde producten" color="#000" class="t-14" backgroundColor="#FFF" />
                        <StackLayout ref="productListContainer">
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script src="./category-details.ts"></script>

<style scoped>
    .bordered {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #000;
    }

    .fontBold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

category-details.ts

```
import AuthBase from '@/shared/auth-base';
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import CategoryService from '@/services/product/category-service';
import TextBlockService from '@/services/product/text-block-service';
import { Expand, Filter } from 'odata-query';
import { ViewTypes } from '@/shared/enums/viewTypes';
import FamilyTree from '@/components/product-tab/_components/family-tree/family-tree.vue';
import ProductService from '@/services/product/product-service';
import ProductList from '@/components/product-tab/_components/product-list/product-list.vue';

@Component({
    name: 'CategoryDetails',
    components: {
        //TODO 2668
        /*        familyTree: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/family-tree/family-tree.vue').default,
        productList: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/product-list/product-list.vue').default,*/
        textBlock: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/text-block/text-block.vue').default,
        youtubeFrame: require('@/components/product-tab/_components/youtube-frame/youtube-frame.vue').default,
    }
})
export default class CategoryDetails extends AuthBase {
    @Prop() readonly categoryId: number;
    @Prop() readonly familyTree: Models.FamilyTreeDto[];

    private readonly categoryService: CategoryService;
    private readonly textBlockService: TextBlockService;
    private readonly productService: ProductService;

    categoryViewType: ViewTypes = ViewTypes.Category;

    category = {} as Models.CategoryDto;

    noImageUrl: string = Vue.prototype.$noImageUrl;

    products: Models.ProductDto[] = [];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.categoryService = new CategoryService();
        this.textBlockService = new TextBlockService();
        this.productService = new ProductService();
    }

    async mounted() {
        await this.getCategoryAsync();
        await this.getTextBlocksAsync();

        this.createFamilyTree();

        await this.getProductsAsync();
        this.createProductsList();
    }

    createFamilyTree() {
        // TODO 2668
        var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(FamilyTree);
        var instance = new ComponentClass({
            propsData: {
                currentId: this.categoryId,
                familyTree: this.familyTree,
                viewType: this.categoryViewType
            }
        });

        instance.$mount(); // pass nothing
        (this.$refs.familyTreeContainer as any).appendChild(instance.$el);
    }

    createProductsList() {
        // TODO 2668
        var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(ProductList);
        var instance = new ComponentClass({
            propsData: {
                items: this.products,                
            }
        });

        instance.$mount(); // pass nothing
        (this.$refs.productListContainer as any).appendChild(instance.$el);
    }

    async getCategoryAsync() {
        const expand: Expand<Models.CategoryDto> = {
            headlineImage: {},
            video: {}
        };

        this.category = await this.categoryService.getCategoryByIdAsync(this.categoryId, expand);
    }

    async getProductsAsync() {
        const filter: Filter = {
            categoryId: this.categoryId
        };

        const expand: Expand<Models.ProductDto> = {
            headlineImage: {}
        };

        this.products = await this.productService.getProductsAsync(filter, expand, 'Name');
    }

    async getTextBlocksAsync() {
        this.category.textBlocks = await this.textBlockService.getTextBlockByProductIdAsync(this.categoryId);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem is not only with the family tree, but also with other components. I have a feeling it has something to do with how the category-details page is initialized.